# Streaming music is sometimes noisy

Tags: itunes, music

Sometimes when I double click a downloaded .pls file to launch a music stream in iTunes, the music is REALLY squelchy.  It literally hurts my ears.  If you have ever heard an old Telephony modem, it sound very similar to that but at one constant pitch.

If I stop and restart it usually fixes the problem (by double-clicking **the same .pls file**) , but I want to know why it does it in the first place.

At present I do not have a recording of the issue, but I will add when I can reproduce it.

OS - Yosemite
Macbook Air

Using the same network (Wifi included) my Linux and Android systems never exhibit this.  Only the iTunes on the Macbook Air.

**I believe I have the answer**.  If I pause the player, it works fine.  If I stop the player unintentionally, by closing the lid for example, the issue presents itself.  Seems like a buffer issue with iTunes I don't know!?

I can consistently repeat this.

Comment: probably streaming low quality based on a guess of your connection speed.

Comment: http://www.speedtest.net/ has my download speed at 13.18 Mbps  - unless it's the streaming service, but I have not experienced this streaming on my Android tablet over same network.

Comment: speedtest gets about 30s to figure it out, a radio station gets milliseconds. If it takes time to instantiate, it could assume you have a slow connection.

Comment: Fair enough.  I just thought I would put it out here to see if I could fix it.  Thanks for your input.  :^)

Comment: you could try the usuals… reboot the router, wire up instead of wifi [that's assuming an Air has ethernet, I've never owned one]

Comment: but you already downloaded the file, so nothing to do with your Internet connection?

Comment: I believe the .pls is just a text "playlist" file that references the locations of the streams.  The quality of the audio files could have been negotiated either when the .pls file was downloaded or as they are called from the .pls file.

Comment: @AllInOne Stopping the stream and restarting (by double-clicking *the same .pls file*) usually fixes the problem.  So I don't think it's an issue with the .pls file.